# Define a model method that gets all records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a rails model called "Post", it represents user's posts on a website.

Each "Post" has a method called "score" which takes its count of views and calculates a score. Score is not stored in the db, it's just a method:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :votes

  def score
    self.votes * 2
  end

  # This should return an object with all the posts, ordered by score. 
  def get_all_posts_sorted_by_rank
    ...
  end
```

Error in Rails console:

```
2.0.0-p451 :001 > Post.get_all_posts_sorted_by_rank

NoMethodError: undefined method `get_all_posts_sorted_by_rank' for Post (call 'Post.connection' to establish a connection):Class
```

Comment: You defined it as an instance method, not a class method.

Comment: extending @DaveNewton comment: The method `get_all_posts_sorted_by_rank` is defined as an instance method (the Model needs to be instanciated to call this method), but you want it as a class method (no need for an Instance of the Model). You can achieve this by defining the method like this: `def self.get_all_posts_sorted_by_rank`

Comment: Thanks for the help - found this solid article about the difference http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/

Comment: Could you also define it in the controller?

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to be a class method, you should use:

```
    def self.get_all_posts_sorted_by_rank
        ...
    end
```

It's probably what you want.

Otherwise, if you want an instance method, you should use the way you are, but you have to instantiate your object before:

```
@post = Post.new #or find(params[:id]) or some other way
@post.get_all_posts_sorted_by_rank #use it
```

But the first case seems more probable.